# Syncframework:Map single table into multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have two tables like the fallowing:

**On server:**

```
      |  Orders Table                             | OrderDetails Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |     Id                                    |   Id
      |     OrderDate                             |   OrderId
      |     ServerName                            |   Product                     
                                                  |   Quantity
```

**On client:**

```
        |  Orders Table                             |  OrderDetails Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   Id                                      |      Id
        |   OrderDate                               |      OrderId
                                                    |      Product                     
                                                    |      Quantity       
                                                    |      ClientName
```

I need to sync the `[Server].[Orders Table].[ServerName]` to `[Client].[OrderDetails Table].[ClientName]`

**The Question:**

What is the true and efficient way of making it?

I know `Deprovisioning` and `provisioning` with different config, is one way of doing it.

So I just wanna know the correct way.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**
Other columns of each table should sync normally (`[Server].[Orders Table].[Id]` to `[Client].[Orders Table].[Id]` ...).

And mapping strategy sometimes changes based on the row of data (which which is `sending/receiving`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Fx is not an ETL tool. simply put, it's DB sync is per table.

if you really want to force it to do what you want, you can simply intercept ChangesSelected event for the OrderDetails table, lookup the extra column from the other table and then dynamically add the column to the dataset before it gets applied on the other side.

see this [link](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/) on how to manipulate the change dataset

Comment: :Thanks , just added more info.

Comment: as i have mentioned, Sync Fx is not an ETL tool. if you can't intercept the changes, there's not much you can do. likewise, you can't dynamically change sync direction based on the row data

Comment: :What if transform selects,inserts and updates by a custom `DbSyncProvider`? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mahjayar/archive/2008/06/25/getting-started-with-dbsyncprovider-peer-to-peer-synchronization.aspx)  ..  the reason I ask is your experience. Thanks June.